# MongoDB aggregation or MapReduce pass down value to each document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mapreduce

I am working on an IOT Project which associates fuel volume information.

I am iterating each MongoDB document and trying to plot the fuel volumes in a graph while omitting noise values. Each document contains the fuel value on every second,

When I plot the data as it is it gives a lot of noise such as

- The vehicle is idle and the same fuel data point is plotted in the graph

[image]

- When the vehicle is moving on a rough road it gives spikes

The data collection simply looks like below

```
{
  _id : 1,
  fuel : 100,
  timestamp: 2020-09-18T06:06:01.628+00:00

},
{
  _id : 2,
  fuel : 100.1,
  timestamp: 2020-09-18T06:06:02.628+00:
}
,{
  _id : 1,
  fuel : 98,
  timestamp: 2020-09-18T06:06:03.628+00:
}
```

I am trying to compare each value of the document fuel value with the previous document fuel value and find the percentage. Then I can give a threshold like plus or minus 5% and filter certain data. This can solve the first problem I am having.

I don't have any idea how to avoid that spikey data points.

I tried the aggregation pipeline and I didn't find a suitable operator or way to save and compare previous data, is there any way to do this. Because I can not smooth data in memory as the data array can be very big from time to time.

Highly appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

map/reduce fans out the input documents to processors, the documents are not necessarily processed sequentially therefore it doesn't make sense to talk about "previous" document.

With the aggregation pipeline you can $group or $bucket to create buckets of data and then operate on the buckets (e.g. to average the values within a bucket).

If you want to do complex math on the values you may need to do that in the application in any event.

Comment: If I take all sum to the application, it takes quite a lot of time, to compute it. We are currently working as like that. But it is crucial that we limit the number of data otherwise we are processing few GBs if the chart is for a month